# How can I avoid changing another textbox when I use two-way binding for quantity?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular13

I'm using *ngFor on my mat-card so it will retrieve all the data from my book table. I also add a textbox on my card so the user can input the quantity. I used the two-way binding on my textbox. My problem is when I changed the quantity on the textbox, all the textboxes are also changed. How can I avoid this to happen? See the picture below:

[image]

Here's my code:

store.component.html

```
<div class="card-container"> 
    <mat-card *ngFor="let card of obs | async; let i = index" class="mt-3">
        <img mat-card-image src="{{card.bookimage}}" width="100" height="200">
        <mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-title>{{card.bookname}}</mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-subtitle>&#8369;{{card.bookprice.toFixed(2)}}<span *ngIf="card.bookunitstock === 0" class="status text-white bg-danger mx-2">Out of Stock</span></mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-actions>
            <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="quantity" name="quantity">
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onAddToCartProduct(card)"><mat-icon class="me-2">add_shopping_cart</mat-icon>Add to cart</button>
        </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

store.component.ts

```
public onAddToCartProduct(book: Book): void {
    const formValue = {
      bookid: book.bookid,
      bookimage: book.bookimage,
      bookname: book.bookname,
      bookprice: book.bookprice,
      bookstatus: book.bookstatus,
      cartitemid: 0,
      category: "Fantasy",
      checkoutstatus: true,
      isbn: book.isbn,
      quantity: this.quantity,
      sku: book.sku,
      totalprice: book.bookprice * this.quantity,
      user_userid: 4
    }
    console.log(formValue);
    this.storeService.addCartProduct(formValue).subscribe(
      (response: Store) => {
        this.products.push(formValue);
        this.grandTotal += (formValue.quantity * formValue.bookprice);
        this.successMessage("added");
    
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        this.errorMessage("Out -of Stock");
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because property `this.quantity` is used on all cards `let card of obs` - they all reference the same prop.

Instead you could bind to prop `quantity` on each individual card with `[(ngModel)]="card?.quantity"`.

And on `formValue` change accordingly `quantity: book.quantity`.

Try to stay consistent when naming obj's, so is it a `book` or a `card`? Good luck!

---

Other option would be to use template variable. We take `input` value from reference `#myInput` and pass it to method `onAddToCartProduct()`.

```html
        <mat-card-actions>
            <input type="number" #myInput name="quantity">
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onAddToCartProduct(card, myInput.value)"><mat-icon class="me-2">add_shopping_cart</mat-icon>Add to cart</button>
        </mat-card-actions>
```

```js
public onAddToCartProduct(book: Book, inputValue: number): void {
    const formValue = {
      bookid: book.bookid,
      bookimage: book.bookimage,
      bookname: book.bookname,
      bookprice: book.bookprice,
      bookstatus: book.bookstatus,
      cartitemid: 0,
      category: "Fantasy",
      checkoutstatus: true,
      isbn: book.isbn,
      quantity: inputValue, // <-----
      sku: book.sku,
      totalprice: book.bookprice * inputValue, // <-----
      user_userid: 4
    }
    console.log(formValue);
    this.storeService.addCartProduct(formValue).subscribe(
      (response: Store) => {
        this.products.push(formValue);
        this.grandTotal += (formValue.quantity * formValue.bookprice);
        this.successMessage("added");
    
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        this.errorMessage("Out -of Stock");
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: I don't have a quantity on my book object. So that's why it is ```this.quantity```.

Comment: I see. Then we could just use template variable. I have updated my answer for this.

Comment: I got this error ```Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.ngtsc(2345)
store.component.ts(12, 70): Error occurs in the template of component StoreComponent.``` on ```inputValue.value```

Comment: I don't understand the origin of this error, what is on line 12? Anyway, it's possible to convert string to a number by casting or parsin it. Try `parseInt()`.

Comment: ```quantity: parseInt(inputValue)``` this one?